# Scalar field theory in xAct mathematica

Tags: xact, variational-calculus

I have this action
[image]

I want to vary this action. How do I do it?

This is my code

```
<< xAct`xTensor`
Block[{Print}, << xAct`xTras`];

DefManifold[M, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, h, i, j, k, l}]
DefMetricPerturbation /. Options@DefMetric
DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], CD, CurvatureRelations -> True]

GBterm = -NoScalar@EulerDensity[CD]
DefScalarFunction[\[Phi]]

MakeRule[-RiemannCD[-a, -b, -c, -d] - g[-a, -d] RicciCD[-b, -c] + 
g[-a, -c] RicciCD[-b, -d] - g[-b, -c] RicciCD[-a, -d] + g[-b, -d] RicciCD[-a, -c] - (1/2) g[-a, -c] g[-b, -d] RicciScalarCD[] - (1/2) g[-a, -d] g[-b, -c] RicciScalarCD[] \[RightArrow] P[-a, -b, -c, -d]]

MakeRule[2 EinsteinCD[-i, -j] CD[a][\[Phi]] CD[-a][\[Phi]] + 4 P[-i, -a, -j, -b] (CD[a][\[Phi]] CD[b][\[Phi]] - CD[a]@CD[b]@\[Phi]) + 4 (CD[-i][\[Phi]] CD[-j][\[Phi]] - CD[-i]@CD[-j]@\[Phi]) CD[-a]@CD[a]@\[Phi] + 4 (CD[-a][\[Phi]] CD[-i][\[Phi]] - CD[-a]@CD[-i]@\[Phi]) (CD[a][\[Phi]] CD[-j][\[Phi]] - CD[a]@CD[-j]@\[Phi]) + g[-i, -j] (2 (CD[-a]@CD[a]@\[Phi] ) (CD[-b]@CD[b]@\[Phi] ) - (CD[a][\[Phi]] CD[-a][\[Phi]]) (CD[b][\[Phi]] CD[-b][\[Phi]]) + 2 CD[-a]@CD[-b]@\[Phi] (2 CD[a][\[Phi]] CD[b][\[Phi]] - CD[b]@CD[a]@\[Phi])) \[RightArrow] H[-i, -j]]

L1 = RicciScalarCD[] + \[Alpha] ( 4 EinsteinCD[a, b] CD[-a][\[Phi]]  CD[-b][\[Phi]] \[Minus] \[Phi] *GBterm + 4 (CD[b]@CD[-b]@\[Phi])*(CD[a][\[Phi]] CD[-a][\[Phi]]) + 2 (CD[a][\[Phi]] CD[-a][\[Phi]])*(CD[b][\[Phi]] CD[-b][\[Phi]]))

VarL[g[-a, -b], CD][L1] // Simplification
```

We get this answer
[image: s]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I  want to verify this result.

Comment: Basically I want to know if my syntax of the code to perform this kind of variation is right so if I have another action with a scalar in it then I can use it.

Comment: It's incredible, the complex scalar field is one of the most basic examples that one may expect to find in every tutorial.. but it's even impossible to find how to define a complex scalar field in xAct!